# How do I know if the page is in Edit Mode from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, client-object-model

Is there a way to find out if a page is in Edit Mode from JavaScript?

I know server-side can be found using `SPContext.Current.FormContext.FormMode` but I can't find any means of doing it from JavaScript.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

Looks like you're looking for MSOLayout_InDesignMode

```
var inDesignMode = document.forms[MSOWebPartPageFormName].MSOLayout_InDesignMode.value;

if (inDesignMode == "1")
{
    // page is in edit mode
}
else
{
    // page is in browse mode
}
```

This will refer to value of the following html input control, which is rendering on the page when it is in edit mode:

```
<input type="hidden" name="MSOLayout_InDesignMode" id="MSOLayout_InDesignMode" value="1" />
```

**Update**: for wiki pages, you will need _wikiPageMode parameter:

```
var wikiInEditMode = document.forms[MSOWebPartPageFormName]._wikiPageMode.value;
if (wikiInEditMode == "Edit")
{
    // wiki page is in edit mode
}
else
{
    // wiki page is not in edit mode
}
```

Comment: Hello @omlin thanks for your quick response. However for some reason this returns always empty regardless of the page mode, any ideas? am I doing anything wrong? I am testing in a standard team site homepage

Comment: I've tested on empty site template. Now I see: this method doesn't work for wiki pages, but for simple pages and webpart pages it works.

Comment: I've updated my answer with solution for wiki pages. Note: this was NOT tested for publishing pages..

Comment: i know little about sharepoint, but i think that `if (inDesignMode = "1")` is a typo :P

Comment: This works! thanks @omlin also there is a javascript method available on wiki page called MSOLayout_IsWikiEditMode() which returns true or false. Anyway this is the right answer too! cheers

Comment: `Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContext.Current.FormContext.FormMode` in code behind - just for reference :)

Comment: For some reason, in IE the **MSOLayout_InDesignMode** is empty in eidt mode on Publishing page. So it's good to check **g_disableCheckoutInEditMode** variable as well. In my case it was the rescue.

Answer (score 41):

```
SP.Ribbon.PageState.Handlers.isInEditMode()
```

Returns true or false. I use this in publishing pages.

Comment: works for SharePoint 2013 December CU

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. This is a documented function. All other answers are hacks.

Comment: This is the only working solution for me and also the cleanest in my opinion. Should be best practice to use the pagestate handler.

Comment: After some tests, the PageState Handlers seem to get initialized very late. So the accepted answer is defenitely worth to consider als a solution.

Comment: There is a timing issue with this solution. On page load it gives you wrong answer, you have to for some time. Check this: https://www.1stquad.com/sharepoint-kompetenz-erfahrung-know-how/blog/default/april-2015/sp-ribbon-pagestate-handlers-isineditmode()-takes

Comment: Doesn't work in 2016 for me

Comment: Always returns false on 2016 for me

Comment: This works fine in 2013. For the timing issues, wrap as follows: `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () { // check if in edit mode }, 'sp.ribbon.js');`

Answer (score 26):

There is also a global object available called '`PageState`'.  Among the various members of state information is "`ViewModeIsEdit`".  If the value of this member is "1" then you are in edit mode (e.g. `PageState.ViewModeIsEdit === "1"`).

**Note:** This variable is initialized after sp.ribbon.js gets loaded and is initialized from the `_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames` array on body load.  So if you plan on using this and need to query a value as soon as the page loads, you will need to do a check to see if the object exists yet.

Comment: this worked for me SP 2010, IE11

Comment: Based on this, I went with `'PageState' in window && window['PageState'].ViewModeIsEdit == 1` (and exactly like that to get around TypeScript warnings)

Comment: +1 for the Typescript warning addition @bdimg

Answer (score 12):

If you're using publishing pages there is a simple solution to execute javascript only in display (or edit) mode. You can use *EditModePanel* control to render html depending on the display mode (display or edit). Here is an example:

```
<PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel ID="EditModelPanel1" runat="server" PageDisplayMode="Edit">
    <h1>You are in EDIT mode</h1>
    <!-- Place you're javascript for execute only in edit mode -->
</PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel>

<PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel ID="EditModelPanel2" runat="server" PageDisplayMode="Display">
    <h1>You are in DISPLAY mode</h1>
    <!-- Place you're javascript for execute only in display mode -->
</PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel>
```

I hope this can help you.

Answer (score 9):

Declare the javascript variable "**IsInPageEditMode**" on master page at top as below...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _fV4UI = true;
    var IsInPageEditMode = false;
</script>
```

Insert the below mention code immediate after the above code...

```
<PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel runat="server" id="EditModePanelJSNone">
     <script type="text/javascript">
        IsInPageEditMode = true;
     </script>
</PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel>
```

Now you can use JavaScript variable **IsInPageEditMode**  whenever you want it...

I am using this code in my existing various applications. We dont face any problem till date. If you face any problem please let me know.... Thanks....

Hope this will help you....

Answer (score 9):

Using JQuery

```
if($("#MSOLayout_InDesignMode").attr('value')== "1")
{

}
```

Comment: This works fine. Not sure why you got down voted.

Answer (score 6):

I have this question many times and bored while trying to find good solution. 
Dont understand why microsoft not include method which can easy determine mode of display page: display or edit. 
It have many advices of check different variables, but it cant uniquely say that page in design on different type of page(webpart page and wiki page) and on postback or not.

Is finally tired me and i write this:

```
    public static bool IsDesignTime()
    {
        if (SPContext.Current.IsDesignTime) return true;

        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["DisplayMode"] != null)
            return true;

        var page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;

        if(page == null) return false;

        var inDesign = page.Request.Form["MSOLayout_InDesignMode"];
        var dispMode = page.Request.Form["MSOSPWebPartManager_DisplayModeName"];
        var wikiMode = page.Request.Form["_wikiPageMode"];
        var we = page.Request.Form["ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$btnWikiEdit"];

        if (inDesign == null & dispMode == null) return false; //normal display

        if (we == "edit") return true; //design on wiki pages

        if (page is WikiEditPage & page.IsPostBack & inDesign == "" & dispMode == "Browse" & wikiMode == "") return false; //display wiki on postback


        if (inDesign == "" & dispMode == "Browse" & (wikiMode == null | wikiMode == "")) return false; //postback in webpart pages in display mode

        if (inDesign == "0" & dispMode == "Browse") return false; //exiting design on webpart pages

        return true;
    }
```

I hope this will save someone some time and nerves.

Comment: Ok, but this is C# not JavaScript, question was specific to JS

Answer (score 5):

How about checking the ID parameter at the query string if there then you are in edit mode

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint! While this post may answer the question, we prefer more details such as "why". Please edit your post with additional details. See [How to Answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for general guidelines.

Comment: When you edit a page and then save it, the Query String parameters persist, so using the Query String wouldn't actually tell you whether or not you are in edit mode definitively.

Answer (score 5):

There must be a bug with the Team site template in SharePoint 2010. This template is the only one where the hidden property `MSOLayout_InDesignMode` does not change to '1' when you switch to Edit/Design mode. It never has a value. Consequently, I have not been able to detect edit mode in a team site. For me, my issue is that I have some Jquery code to leverage Typekit functionality (more graphical fonts using CSS) and when this runs in edit mode, it causes a `sp.ui.rte.debug.js access denied` error, which in turn prevents any of the ribbon drop downs (e.g. font) from working.

Comment: Hi Alan, the Default page for the team site is a wikipage so you should try @omlin second suggestion document.forms[MSOWebPartPageFormName]._wikiPageMode.value, hope this helps

Comment: Also @Matt-Dempsey suggestion works well!

Answer (score 4):

```
alert(g_disableCheckoutInEditMode);
```

Comment: While this post may answer the question, we prefer more details such as "why". Please edit your post with additional details. See [answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for general guidelines.

Answer (score 3):

I just use this handy javascript function...

```
function IsDesignMode() {
    var inDesign = document.forms[MSOWebPartPageFormName].MSOLayout_InDesignMode;
    if (inDesign != null && inDesign.value == "1") return true;

    var dispMode = document.forms[MSOWebPartPageFormName].MSOSPWebPartManager_DisplayModeName;
    if (dispMode != null && dispMode.value == "Edit") return true;

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`SP.Ribbon.PageState` is commonly used to perform specific actions based on the state. `isInEditMode()` is used to determines whether the page is currently being edited.

```
var InEditMode = SP.Ribbon.PageState.Handlers.isInEditMode();

if(InEditMode){

       // page in edit mode
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This has worked for me for many years on publishing/non-publishing pages/everywhere.  Just another option to add to the already large list added here.

```
this.inEditMode = function () {
  var result = (window.MSOWebPartPageFormName != undefined) && ((document.forms[window.MSOWebPartPageFormName] && document.forms[window.MSOWebPartPageFormName].MSOLayout_InDesignMode && ("1" == document.forms[window.MSOWebPartPageFormName].MSOLayout_InDesignMode.value)) || (document.forms[window.MSOWebPartPageFormName] && document.forms[window.MSOWebPartPageFormName]._wikiPageMode && ("Edit" == document.forms[window.MSOWebPartPageFormName]._wikiPageMode.value)));
  return result || false;
},
```