# Javascript: How can I tell if the page is being customized (and not personalized)?

Tags: javascript

[How do I know if the page is in Edit Mode from JavaScript?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/12792/6303) tells me how to know if a page is in *Design* mode. I need to distinguish *between* the *two* design modes: *customizing* vs *personalizing*.

How can I detect, using Javascript, when a page is being *customized* ("Site Actions" > "Edit Page") without getting false positives when it is being *personalized* ("Welcome Menu" > "Personalize this Page")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In design and view modes, when a user is looking at personalized page, look for PageView=Personal in query string (window.location).