# Save/Leave Event after editing a Page

Tags: 2013, javascript, events, edit

I need to fire some functionality from javascript when a user has finished editing a page and saves it or leaves the editing mode.

Is there a possibility to catch the event?

Answer (score 1):

Use `window.onbeforeunload` in edit mode to perform all your operations. [Here is](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/12792/how-do-i-know-if-the-page-is-in-edit-mode-from-javascript) how you check edit/display mode

```
    window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    var message = "Your confirmation message goes here.",
     e = e || window.event;
     // For IE and Firefox
     if (e) {
        e.returnValue = message;
     }

      // For Safari
      return message;
};
```

Comment: Can I determine from the returnValue if the site was really saved on the server? Because as I understand, this event is always fired when user leaves edit mode, regardless if he saved the site or discarded check out.

Comment: Unfortunately it is also not possible to gather user information in the on onbeforeunload, because you can not fire alerts or confirm messages.