# Hide Master page left navigation and top ribbon but should be able to add webparts easily

Tags: 2010, web-part, custom-masterpage

I am developing master page. I don't want to show **top ribbon** and left **navigation menu** to user.

So I am hiding it using css

```
#s4-leftpanel,#s4-ribbonrow {
 display:none !important;
}
```

The challenge I am facing is if I keep this css in master page. I am not able to create pages easily. Also not able to access ribbon.

So I created master page with both visible and created a page layout based on master page. and added this css to it. But again the same problem.

I need to make sure I can add webparts to any pages I create using the ribbon and access the left navigation. but not the users.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: well, you _could_ add a little bit of javascript at the bottom of the master page to display the ribbon and leftpanel if the current user is some administrative account? something like `if(_spPageContextInfo.userLoginName == "<adminLoginNamehere>"){$("#s4-ribbonrow).show();}` maybe

Comment: you can check edit mode but it only covers adding webparts I guess, http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/12792/how-do-i-know-if-the-page-is-in-edit-mode-from-javascript

Comment: @TiagoDuarte I am more worried about editing/removing existing webparts as well. You think this will work with it?

Comment: @garglblarg Can we do it group specific instead of user specific?

Comment: @Gaurravs i guess so, see this thread regarding group membership checking: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22126724/2608528

Comment: @garglblarg thanks for the help.. Tiago's approach worked easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to validate if the page is in [edit mode](http://%3Cstyle%3E%20#s4-leftpanel,#s4-ribbonrow%20%7B%20%20display:none%20!important;%20%7D%20%3C/style%3E).

But since you'd rather be able to still see everything as an elevated user, perhaps using `SPSecurityTrimmedControl` is a better choice.

```
<style>
/*hide stuff from users*/
#s4-leftpanel,#s4-ribbonrow {
 display:none !important;
}
</style>

<Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl runat="server" PermissionsString="FullMask">
<style>
/*show stuff for full control users*/
#s4-leftpanel,#s4-ribbonrow {
block !important;
}
</style>
</Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>
```