# hide ribbon and suite bar based on user type in sharepoint 2013 site

Tags: sharepoint-designer, development, html

I have a site with a group "owners" and "members". I do not want members to have access to the ribbon or the the suite bar what do I have to modify in the master page to do that I believe I have found the correct section of the master page. I believe I should use the command:

`<SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>` around the `<div id="s4-ribbonrow">` element but I do not know how to correctly apply this. Everything I have tried so far results in an error on the site

```
</SharePoint:AjaxDelta>
        <div id="ms-hcTest"></div>
        <div id="s4-ribbonrow" >
        <div id="globalNavBox" class="noindex">
    <div id="ribbonBox">
    <div id="s4-ribboncont">
        <SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaSPRibbon" BlockElement="true" runat="server">
            <SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ID="GlobalDelegate0" ControlId="GlobalSiteLink0" />
            <SharePoint:SPRibbon
                runat="server"
                PlaceholderElementId="RibbonContainer"
                CssFile="" >
                <SharePoint:SPRibbonPeripheralContent
                    runat="server"
                    CssClass="ms-core-defaultFont ms-dialogHidden"
                    Location="TabRowLeft">
                </SharePoint:SPRibbonPeripheralContent>
                <SharePoint:SPRibbonPeripheralContent
                    runat="server"
                    Location="TabRowRight"
                    ID="RibbonTabRowRight"
                    CssClass="s4-trc-container s4-notdlg ms-core-defaultFont">
                    <SharePoint:SPSharePromotedActionButton runat="server"/>
                    <SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="PromotedActions" AllowMultipleControls="true" />
                    <SharePoint:SPSyncPromotedActionButton runat="server"/>
                    <SharePoint:PageStateActionButton id="PageStateActionButton" runat="server" Visible="false" />
```

Comment: Do you have to do it using markup? Would you consider using javaScript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide Master page left navigation and top ribbon but should be able to add webparts easily](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/187050/hide-master-page-left-navigation-and-top-ribbon-but-should-be-able-to-add-webpar)

Comment: I don't recommend wrapping SPSec around existing controls as it might break the page for those users. what you can do is wrap it around conditional CSS like in the answer I suggested above

Comment: Thanks alot very helpful I have added the solution to my problem if anyone ever needs

Comment: @M_kul you should post it as an answer instead

Answer (score 4):

For anyone interested I accomplished this using a simple css edit in the head of the page code below if anyone needs:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #contentBox  {margin-left: 20px !important;}
    #SearchBox {display:none;}
    #suiteBarTop {display:none !important;}
    #s4-ribbonrow{display:none !important;}
</style>
<Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl runat="server"PermissionsString="FullMask">
<style type="text/css">
    #suiteBarTop{display:block !important;}
    #s4-ribbonrow{display:block !important;}
</style>
</Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Hide ribbon using  `SPSecurityTrimmedControl` based on `PermissionsString`  like

◾FullMask.
◾EmptyMask.
◾ManagePermissions.
◾ManageSubwebs.
◾ManageWeb.
◾AddAndCustomizePages.
◾BrowseDirectories.
◾ViewPages.
◾EnumeratePermissions.
◾ManageAlerts.

- To hide Ribbon in SharePoint 2013 using CSS check [How to hide Ribbon in SharePoint 2013 using CSS](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/03/12/how-to-hide-ribbon-in-sharepoint-2013-using-css/)
- Also for SharePoint 2010 check [How to hide Ribbon in SharePoint 2010 using CSS](https://blog.devoworx.net/2012/12/27/how-to-hide-ribbon-in-sharepoint-2010-using-css/)